# Custom folder with PDF files (not in WP Library) - Create url for each file

Tags: url-rewriting, pdf

I have a folder mywebsite.com/wp-content/customUploads which contains hundreds of pdf files.

At this point the url to see a pdf file is for example:
mywebsite.com/wp-content/customUploads/myfile.pdf

My goal is to have a url for each PDF file like:
mywebsite.com/pdf-files/myfile.pdf

So if a user request the above url, the website will load the pdf file.

Is there a way to request the url:

- mywebsite.com/pdf-files/myfile.pdf

and this url is translated to the following, so the file could be loaded correctly?

- mywebsite.com/wp-content/customUploads/myfile.pdf

Comment: A URL such as that would bypass WP logic entirely, so any rewrite would have to take place outside of WP.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Give me an example so i can understand your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: I can't give you an example because by it's nature this is not a WordPress question. The URL you want to use ends in `.pdf`, so no PHP whatsoever will be engaged to access that file, therefore nothing you do in WP will help. You'll probably have to use `htaccess` or similar, [such as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664041/how-to-write-a-rule-for-pdf-file-that-exist-in-a-folder/36747705).

Comment: Ok, so i am looking for htaccess rewrite rules or something like that.

Comment: I just linked to a post that should at least point you in the right direction. You'll notice that post was on stackoverflow, rather than WPSE, as general htaccess rewrite rules are off topic here.

Comment: Thank you @Vancoder.

Comment: this sounds more like a redirect than a rewrite, otherwise this would be an Apache/Nginx question

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in WordPress by using custom rewrite rules.

Use this code inside theme's function.php file or inside a plugin.

```
// 1- Create a custom query var
    add_filter( 'query_vars', function ( $query_vars ) {
        $query_vars[] = 'my_pdf_file';
        return $query_vars;
    });

    // 2- Add a custom rewrite rule.
    // NOTE: rewrite rules must be flushed for this rule to work.
    // You can flush rewrite it by saving permalinks from dashboard.
    add_action('init', function (){
        add_rewrite_rule('^pdf-files/([a-zA-Z0-9 _\-]+\.pdf)$','index.php?my_pdf_file=$matches[1]' );
    });

    // 3- Find and display the PDF file when a pdf file link is visited.
    add_action('template_redirect', function () {

        $pdf_file_name = get_query_var('my_pdf_file');

        // Don't do anything if no file name is supplied
        if(! $pdf_file_name) {
            return;
        }

        // Create the file path with the supplied name.
        $pdf_file_path = \WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/customUploads/' . $pdf_file_name;

        // Show 404 page if invalid file name is supplied
        if(! is_file($pdf_file_path)) {
            global $wp_query;
            $wp_query->set_404();
            return;
        }

        // Read and display the PDF file
        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        readfile($pdf_file_path);
        exit;

    });
```

Don't forget to save permalinks from "permalinks settings" page on WordPress dashboard to flush rewrite rules after using the above code.